# What's the real use of using n[c-'0']?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm a novice in C and I came across the code like this :

```
int n[10];
if(c>='0' && c<='9')
++n[c-'0']
```

In `if` loop why we have to use single quotes around `0`, whats the use of it, why we can't define `0` as an integer straight away? And in the second line of code `++n[c-'0']`, whats the use of using array like this, in sense why we need to subtract `0`(once again why the use of single quotes in this context?) from `c` in the array index?

If i do like this `n[c-'0']`, the result of index operation(`c-'0'`) will be an character or integer?

Given that can anyone say me, whats the real use of such array and what are the disadvantages well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C, `'0'` is an integer whose value represents the digit zero as a character, not the value 0, which would be the null character. Other answers have omitted this, but it's important to note that the C language mandates that the decimal digits have consecutive values, so that if `c` is a digit, `c-'0'` is the numeric value of that digit, i.e.

```
'0'-'0' = 0
'1'-'0' = 1
'2'-'0' = 2
.
.
.
'9'-'0' = 9
```

Comment: if i do like this `n[c-'0']`, the result of index operation will be an character or integer?

Comment: It should be noted that the standard only guarantees that the digits are consecutive, it doesn't make such a guarantee for any other character. See for example the EBCDIC table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code

Comment: @Secure: Any compilers who use anything other than ASCII? If not, that point is fairly pedantic. What does a person beginning to learn C want to know about the specifics of the language standards?

Comment: @EXIT: so they don't do `n[c - 0x30]` instead of `n[c - '0']`.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE: People learning C should learn what the standard requires in cases like this, because otherwise they're prone to write over-complex obfuscated code trying to be portable - for example, using a lookup table to convert digits to values rather than just using subtraction.

Comment: @sixlettervariables & R..: Language specific implementations and cross-compiler portability is not something a student beginning to learn C should worry about. If you talk about EBCDIC to a student at beginner level, you are probably doing something fundamentally wrong as a teacher. His compiler uses the ASCII table -- on his compiler '0' **is** 48. Knowing about the most used conversion table from characters to numbers *is* important; considering cross-compiler portability and language specific implementations *is not*. There is a time and place for everything.

Comment: The issue is that beginners have often *already hard about* portability issues, and they're often under the false impression that C allows the implementation to do "anything it wants" in many areas where there are actually strict requirements. This leads to nonsensically "over-portable" code.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE: You have a point there, but this is not a closed class of beginners. This is Stack Overflow, where programmers of all levels are lurking around, reading this question, its answers and comments for years to come.

Comment: The level of the student should be judged according to the individual in question. In this particular case (Ant's), it  suggests that he isn't aware of the relationship between a character and its numerical representation. At this level, it's more productive to relate it to the ASCII table, and not be "technically correct" and go into "the odd cases", which confuse far more than help. So to comment directly: I don't think Ant is better off considering portability, and I don't know what you mean by "over-portable" code.

Comment: @Secure: I also agree that both of you have a point. And that it's good to point out that the actual conversion table isn't guaranteed (but most likely) to be ASCII, so using '0' is better than 0x30 or 48. But sometimes I feel stack overflow values technical correctness, over helpfulness. That is my only beef :)

Comment: @Ant's: I believe that in C, there is no "character" type as such, and `char` is a (small) integral type. In an ASCII compiler, the literal `'0'` will be interpreted as the integer `48`.

Answer (score 6):

`c` is (likely) a `char`, which also has an integer representation and in C it can be converted implicitly. `'0'` is the character zero, and a convenient feature of numeric characters is that they are laid out sequentially in their integer representations.

So, now that you know each character has an integer representation and that the number characters are laid out sequentially, you can convert a character to its integer representation using simple subtraction.

```
'0' - '0' == 0
'1' - '0' == 1
'2' - '0' == 2
/* and so on and so forth */
```

So if you would like to count the occurrences of digits in a string, you can use this to your advantage:

```
int n[10]; /* 10 digits */

n['0' - '0'] /* where we store the counts for the character 0, aka n[0] */
n['1' - '0'] /* where we store the counts for the character 1, aka n[1] */
```

Answer (score 5):

As you may already know, computers represent characters as numbers. The C standard requires that this representation must ensure that the digits must follow each other. So if n is the code of `'0'` then n + 9 is the code of `'9'`. For ASCII, these values are 48 and 57 respectively.

The code example you posted tries to be encoding agnostic so instead of checking against 48 or 57, it uses `'0'` as a portable constant.

Answer (score 3):

`'0'` and `'9'` are of `int` types. Their values are 48 and 57 respectively (since 48 and 57 are ASCII values of characters `'0'` and `'9'`).

So you are probably holding in `n` an array for counting digits.

So this expression (if you are storing digit characters on `c`):

```
++n[c-'0'];
```

Means:

1. Take n's position number `c-'0'` (`c` holds a character with a digit on it)
2. Increment that position by one.

So `n` will be:

```
n[0] = x; // count of 0 characters
n[1] = x; // count of 1 characters
n[2] = x; // count of 2 characters
n[3] = x; // count of 3 characters
n[4] = x; // count of 4 characters
n[5] = x; // count of 5 characters
n[6] = x; // count of 6 characters
n[7] = x; // count of 7 characters
n[8] = x; // count of 8 characters
n[9] = x; // count of 9 characters
```

For example, let's say `c` is equal to character `2`. `2`'s ascii value is `50`. So `n[50-48]` becomes `n[2]`. So you end up using third element of array `n` to store `2` character count.

Comment: Except if they're 240 and 249 respectively :) (Yes, I memorized the EBCDIC codes just for the purpose of posting snarky remarks like this.)

Comment: No, in C the are of type `int`.

Comment: The important part is they are laid out sequentially. Their values are irrelevant as long as you're using subtraction to map them.

Comment: +1 For actually explaining the purpose of `++n` and not just the char subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), as it probably explains it well enough by itself. The decimal representation for the character '0' is 48, '1' is 49, etc. Most, if not all compilers, follow this conversion table.

By subtracting '0' (most likely the number 48), you essentially turn the character representation of the variable `c` into a number representation.

**edit:** As mentioned in the comments, I should point out that the number representation of '0' or '9' doesn't necessarily follow the ASCII conversion table (although I believe all common compilers do). This is a technical detail, and belongs in a discussion of the ANSI C specification, and not in an answer directed to someone learning the language.

Should Ant's happen to write `int number = '0';`, and wonder why it stores the number 48, it's because his compiler follows the ASCII conversion. *This* is both useful and helpful for a person learning the basics of C. Show me a compiler that doesn't do this, that isn't some obscure rarity, and I'll gladly leave it at that, but I think more often than not SO values pedantry over helpful replies.

That said, it's still a good thing to never use the actual number representations. That is, always prefer writing '0' over 48. But it's nice to know why '0' most likely is represented by the number 48.

Comment: @R. Martinho It definitely is about ascii.

Comment: @meagar: The C++ language standard guarantees that the following relationship, '0' < '9', shall be true regardless of the internal character representation (e.g. ASCII, UNICODE, etc). Thus it is not about ASCII.

Comment: @Thomas: Fair enough, though I believe all implementations follow the ASCII table conversion for all characters represented by values 0-127, even though technically as you mention, the only guarantee is some logical ordering. However, pedagogically, it's more helpful for a novice in C to think of cases like '0' and 'a' as a simple ASCII to char conversion. This will always (prove me wrong) be the case, so being overly technical is counter-productive to learning.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE: EBCDIC uses 240-249 for the digits. You don't need to teach them that '0' is 48. You only need to teach them that `'1'` is `'0' + 1`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct R.Martinho, but can you give me an example of a C compiler that would output anything other than 48 if you executed the following: printf("%i",'0'); I know 'technically correct' is called the best kind of correct, but he said he was a newbie in C, and his understanding of why that outputs 48 in relation to the ASCII table, IMHO trumps by far any technical details as to why that isn't guaranteed by the language specification.

Comment: @R: Also, given that their compiler follows the ASCII conversion, '0' **is** 48. Just take a look at the assembly code, and you'll see it there. If you want to be a good teacher, teach them both, and never mention language specific implementation or obscurities until they know more than the basics.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE - agreed.  If my first CS teacher would have quoted the standard to be technically correct, I probably wouldn't be a dev today.  There is a time and a place to be technically correct, but this concerns helping a rookie learn, and so quoting the standard concerning internal representation of characters isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2):

Taken out of context, it's impossible to say *why* the author might have done this.

What the code does is loop over the characters `'0'` to `'9'`, possibly to compare them with some user input. During the body of the loop, the characters are mapped to the integers `0..9` for the purposes of indexing the array `n`.

Characters in C can behave like integers when involved in arithmetic, by being converted to their ASCII integer representation. The first time through the loop, `c` is `0`, and `'0' - '0'` is integer `0`, regardless of what the integer value of `'0'` is. That is, `x - x` will always equal 0; the actual value of `x` is unimportant in this case.

Given this, and the fact that the ASCII values are sequential, incrementing from `0` to `9`, you can tell that the second time through the loop when `c` will be `'1'`, that `'1' - '0'` is integer `1`, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

`'0'` denotes a character value, which can be silently converted to integer, and the result is (usually) the ASCII value of the character `'0'` (which happens to be 48). The `if` condition verifies that `c` is (convertible into) a character value which contains a numerical digit. This is possible because the numerical digits 0 to 9 are represented by consecutive values in the [ASCII chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/), from 48 to 57, respectively. If you subtract the ASCII value of `'0'` (i.e. 48) from the ASCII value of any numerical digit character, you get the numerical value of that digit (from 0 to 9).

So the code above indexes into an array of counters, possibly to count the appearances of each numerical digit in some piece of text.

Comment: The encoding is not necessarily ASCII. That's just the trick, it works with any encoding.

Comment: @Jens, any encoding which represents numeric digits with consecutive values in the right order, that is. E.g. EBCDIC happens to do that too, but it can cause nasty surprises to someone attempting a naive ordering of alphabetic characters :-)

Comment: if i do like this `n[c-'0']`, the result of index operation will be an character or integer?

Comment: @Ant, `c-'0'` yields an integer result (both character values get silently converted to int before the subtraction). `n[c-'0']` yields the value of the appropriate element in the array `n`, which in this case is most probably an array of numeric values (but at least of a type having `operator++` defined).

Answer (score 2):

First, `if` is not a loop, it is a statement.  There's only going to be one pass through the code.

That means the first line can read `if c is a digit` and the second line combines conversion of the ascii digit to an integer digit (and increments the element of the n array to count that digit).

Answer (score 1):

Because `c` is a character and not an integer.

The ASCII value of '0' is 48 so a '0' would be index 48 in the `n[c]` statement and the programmer wanted '0' to be index 0 because `n` was defined `n[10]`, so the ASCII value is converted to its integer equivalent by subtracting the code for '0' so: `'0' - '0' = 0`, `'1' - '0' = 1`, etc. The ASCII codes for '0' to '9' are 48 to 57 so the conversion is sound.

As for why, I guess someone is counting the frequency of the digits '0' to '9' in some text.

Answer (score 1):

This allows to use a `char` as an index of an array. For example you could define a string `"012345"`, probably read from an external file, and compute for each character `c-'0'`, which will give the integers `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This (terrible) code maps the ASCII values of the digits 0..9 to zero based indexes. `'0'` is of type `char`, which is a numeric type. The numeric value of `'0'` is usually `48`. Subtracting `48` from a `char` representing a digit will give you the "value" of the `char`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to convert the ascii value of something to its number. In C the ascii value of the char '0' is 48. So subtracting:

```
'0' - '0' = 0
'1' - '0' = 1
 ...
 c - '0' = <whatever the decimal number of c is>
```

Conveniently the ASCII decimal number increments are consecutive otherwise this trick won't work. In other words `c` has to be one of '0'..'9' for this to work. This explains the restriction:

```
if(c>='0' && c<='9')
```

Answer (score 1):

-'0' subtracts the ASCII value of zero(48) from the given single-digit integer(should only contain 1 digit) the digits from '0' to '9' are stored sequentially in the ASCII code, therefore subtracting the 0's ASCII value from the given single-digit integer will give the numeric value of integer itself. for example:- the ascii value of '4' is 52 subtracting the ascii value of '0' which is 48 from 52 will give us the numeric value 4 which is equal to the given integer, therefore we use subtraction and not an addition of +'0' and also subtraction or addition of any other value will also NOT result in the same numeric value of the given integer.