# K&R 1.6 Arrays // Digit representation in an array construct

Tags: c, arrays, digit, kernighan-and-ritchie

I found this example code on using arrays in the C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main () {
    int c, i;
    int ndigit[10];

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i]=0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c - '0'];

printf("digits =");
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
}
```

I never saw arrays before, but I think I got it.
Still, I'm not sure on why the digit values have to be inserted in `'..'` nor why the assignement of `i` has to be expressed as `c-'0'`.

This is a passage of the book that should clarify my doubts:

> This particolar program relies on the properties of the character representation of the digits. For example the text `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` determines whether the characters in `c` is a digit. If it is, the numeric value if that digit is `c - '0'`.

I don't understand how can these values be used in arithmetical expressions if they are characters, is it because they are mapped to numerical values?

Then why the whole program just doesn't work if they are written as numbers as in `if (c >= 0 && c <= 9)` nor it works if `c` isn't written in that way (which to my understanding is just "whatever number `c` is minus 0).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the real use of using n\[c-'0'\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403741/whats-the-real-use-of-using-nc-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: a "char" is just a one-byte-long integer.

> I don't understand how can these values be used in arithmetical expressions if they are characters, is it because they are mapped to numerical values?

In C, a char is the "smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character set. It is an integer type." [1]. Normally, char is equivalent to "a one-byte-long integer", so they can hold values from 0 to (2^8)-1, or [0,255].

That being said, when you write

```
char c = '9';
```

You are saying "c is a one-byte-long integer whose value is the character-set representation of the character 9". By looking at the most common character set, the ASCII table [2], we see that the character 9 has an integer value of 57, so the above expression is equivalent to

```
char c = 57;
```

To convert a digit's character-set value to the digit itself (e.g. '9' to 9, or 57 to 9), you can rely on a property of character sets that digits are always stored sequentially and increasingly, and just subtract by the value of '0', which in ASCII is 48, so:

```
char c;
c = '9' - '0'; /* = 9 In any character set */
c = 57 - 48;   /* = 9 */
c = '9' - 48;  /* = 9 In ASCII */
c = 57 - '0';  /* = 9 In ASCII */
```

Keep in mind that while ASCII is the most common character set, this is actually machine-dependent.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types

[2] http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: "...only those in the ASCII table can be printed
as characters." nope. What do you think will happen if I try to print the value 5 as a character?

Comment: Do not equal C to ASCII. There is no reason other than, yes, admittedly, it is *most used*, but by the same token you could say "In Windows Codepage 1252..."

Comment: @CoolGuy: well, it depends... what is your OS? Compiler? Character encoding?  (Which is *exactly* why nobody should mention "ASCII" -- it is *irrelevant* to the OP's question.)

Comment: @davir: ".. rely on a property of the ASCII table that digits are stored sequentially ..", no, the C Specification says they must be in the encoding used by the compiler. If it isn't, in ASCII, you cannot use ASCII.

Comment: .. re: your last comment (sorry, I was typing): it doesn't matter. As long as `'0'..'9'` are consecutive (and they **must be**), you can do without mentioning ASCII at all.

Comment: @Jongware You are right, on page 23 of the second edition of K&R it says "This only works if '0','1', ..., '9' have consecutive increasing values. Fortunately, this is true for all character sets". I can understand that this is convenient, but can you explain why this **must** be true?

Comment: (We're being accused of chatting...) For me, "it must" because the specs say so. If the OP's compiler is not compliant and does not follow this one rule, the entire discussion is pointless...

Comment: @Jon , It depends? I thought that non-printable characters are well, not printable and trying to print them will result in UB. My OS is Windows and I use GCC. And why does your comment have unusual spacing(I'm using an old phone that supports SO partially)?

Comment: Oh @Cool one, "it depends" because a character 5 is only not printable in ASCII. And even then, some consoles may *still* output a character -- from (ancient) memory, I think '5' yielded an Ace of Clubs character on my first PC, with MS DOS 3.31, using Turbo C. See? A specific compiler, OS, and OEM encoding. YMMV.

Comment: @Jongware , I see. So, it is not UB trying to print them?

Comment: @CoolGuy: it's not against the rules of C, it will only delegate the problem to the console. Using `write` or `fwrite` you can even dump literal zeroes -- some consoles will show "^@", some will show a space. Perhaps some will crash too.

Answer (score 2):

if you see the man page of `getchar()` it says

> ....reads the next character from stdin and returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`....

So, an input of a *digit* [example, `9`] is treated as a `char` input and the corresponding encoded [Usually ASCII] value is returned by `getchar()`.

Now coming to your question(s),

> why the digit values have to be inserted in '..'

A *digit* [or any other character, for that matter], written as `'.'`, represents the corresponding ASCII value of the same. Check the ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For understanding, a `9` is a `9` whereas a `'9'` represents the correcsponding ASCII `57`.

> why the assignment of i has to be expressed as c-'0'.

If you notice the ASCII table closely, you can see, the corresponding values of `0` to `9` are in sequence. So, to get the particular digit *as* an `int` value, we can do `c - '0'` which is same as `c - 48` which will give us the digit *as* an `int`.

Comment: Actually, "in the encoding as used by the compiler" (the specification does not mention or recommend a certain encoding, other than some restrictions).

Comment: "A digit written as.." No. It's not limited to *digits*.

Comment: @Jongware I got your point sir, my choice of words are wrong. Can you suggest how to state it properly?

Comment: "A digit,or any other character ,written as..." would be correct.

Comment: @Jongware Shall i change that to "`character` input"?

Comment: Yeah, as @CoolGuy suggests. For complete understanding, you should remove or clarify the "ASCII" part -- the system is totally independent from the used encoding (although per C specs, the digits must occur in sequence, which is a convenience -- for digits only).

Comment: so, in `c - '0'` the operands are the decimal values assigned to the given characters and the result is just a "plain number"?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how can these values be used in arithmetical
>   expressions if they are characters, is it because they are mapped to
>   numerical values?

`getchar()` returns the character read.Prototype for it is

```
int getchar(void)
```

When a character is read `getchar()` returns the ASCII value of the char read.

The ASCII value for char's 0 to 9 are contiguous. So just making use of it if we have

```
char ch = '5'; 
int i = ch - '0'; /* 53 - 48 = 5 */
```

will give you the integer value 5. Converting character to integer. The arithmetic is performed by implicit conversion.

If you have a character '8' then this doesn't give you the integer value `8` but retuns ASCII value 56. So during arithmetic `ch - '0'` since both are char's the respective ASCII values are used and the arithmetic operation is performed

Comment: Shouldn't you also point out the *character* notation is not limited to digits only? OP seems to think they are linked.

Comment: @Jongware The comment part doesn't help ?

Comment: No, there is no link between `8` and `'8'` other than that the encoding specified by `'8'` represents a certain character with that value. It has no "numerical" meaning -- compare with `'A'`, which is also a character literal but not a number. The numerical link between `'8'` and `8` is *created* in the OP's code. You could create a similar link for "A..J".

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks typing mistake you are right 0 -9 are contiguous